# Pagebreak on vsword

Tags: php, html, cpu-word

I'm using this library [VsWord](https://github.com/vench/vsword) to convert some HTML data on my db into a Microsoft Word Document. But I'm not being successful at parsing this HTML code and also put a PageBreak in beetween some data.

My code so far is like this:

```
$doc = new VsWord();  
$parser = new HtmlParser($doc);

while($row = $connection->fetch($query)){
    $filename = $row['permalink'];

    $parser->parse('<h3 style="text-align:center;">'.html_entity_decode($row['title']).'</h3>');
    $parser->parse(html_entity_decode($row['content']));
    $parser->parse(new PageBreakNode());
}

$doc->saveAs('../temp/'.$filename.'.docx');
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a word document with Microsoft Word and I written something, ctl+enter (for a break page) and written another text. Then I saved the document as HTML and when I opened it I saw that the code for create a break page was this:

```
<br clear=all style='mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-before:always'>
```